# efficient way to declare and delete variables using function

Tags: r

please suggest a more efficient method in declaring and removing a list of variable using function call. The problem is that for each `abc` global variable added in `init.trial`, I have to add one `abc` into `rm.init.trial`.

```
init.trial <- function(){
  xyz <<- 1
  abc <<- "hi"
}

rm.init.trial <- function(){
  rm(xyz, abc, pos=1)
}
```

I have consider using `switch` inside `init.trail`, but it is no different than the above. (I still have to type `abc` twice: one for init, another one to remove)

Comment: Generally this is something you try to avoid in R. Dealing with functions that leak variables into different scopes isn't very fun to reason about. Functions should return values as needed. Or use something like `with`: `with(list(xyz=1, abc="hi"), print(paste(xyz, abc)))`

Comment: Your function should return a list of values, or even an environment with values instead. Then you can just drop the whole list or environment when you are done with it. Don't pollute your global scope.

Comment: beavis11111, I agree with MrFlick, and I cannot stress enough that this method of dealing with a function's *effects* can very easily cause significant stress and headache. Function-testing and project reproducibility are high on the list, but they are not the only issues. Your code that calls `init.trial` should always collect the return value (e.g., `myval <- init.trial()`), and then when you are done with that data, you can use the standard function `rm(myval)` instead of having to try to remember all of the variable names (and piercing function boundaries).